# My bike's front suspension got stiffer on its own

Tags: suspension, hardtail

Yesterday I was riding my bicycle and realized that my front suspension got stiffer than a month ago. I tried locking it then releasing, adjusting the stiffness but it's still not the same as before.

Comment: What kind of suspension do you have? What kind of bike do you have?

Comment: Have you removed and re-installed the front wheel? It could be slanted. Or did you run into an obstacle or mounted a kerb?

Comment: I don't know the model of the bike but its a hardtail merida mtb 50' frame and the suspension is coil not air

Comment: Have you turned the preload knob, usually top of left side of the fork?

Comment: Yeah. It's not quite the same as it was one month ago. Well i think its aging what did it